# stockChart shows future date label

Tags: highcharts

On candlestick and ohlc chart despite that data up to day xAxis shows tomorrow's date.
Setting endOnTick, max, softMax, ceiling on xAxis does not change anything.

Anyone has an idea how to set the last label on xAxis chart to the last point on the chart?

Sample can be reproduced by using this code:

```
var today = new Date(),
day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
title: {
    text: 'Current Date Indicator'
},
xAxis: [{
    id: 'bottom-datetime-axis',
    type: 'datetime',
    max: today.getTime()
}],
series: [{
    name: 'Project 1',
    borderRadius: 3,
    xAxis: 0,
    type: 'candlestick',

    data: [{
        x: today.getTime() - (11 * day),
open: 5,
high: 7,
low: 2,
close: 6,            
        y: 2
    }, {
        x: today.getTime() - (10 * day),
open: 3,
high: 6,
low: 2,
close: 5,            
        y: 1
    }, {
        x: today.getTime() - (9 * day),
open: 5,
high: 7,
low: 2,
close: 6,            
        y: 2
    }, {
        x: today.getTime() - (8 * day),
open: 3,
high: 6,
low: 2,
close: 5,            
        y: 1
    }, {
        x: today.getTime() - (7 * day),
open: 5,
high: 7,
low: 2,
close: 6,            
        y: 2
    }, {
        x: today.getTime() - (4 * day),
open: 3,
high: 6,
low: 2,
close: 5,            
        y: 1
    }, {
        x: today.getTime() - (3 * day),
open: 5,
high: 7,
low: 2,
close: 6,            
        y: 1
    }, {
        x: today.getTime() - (2 * day),
open: 3,
high: 6,
low: 2,
close: 5,            
        y: 1
    }, {
        x: today.getTime() - day,
open: 3,
high: 6,
low: 2,
close: 5,            
        y: 3
    }, {
        x: today.getTime(),
open: 5,
high: 7,
low: 2,
close: 6,            
        y: 2
    }]
}]
});
```

or use Online demo which can be find here: https://jsfiddle.net/gt9cr4x7/1/

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tickPositioner` function and return only those tick positions that have a lower value than the last point `x` value:

```
xAxis: {
    ...,
    tickPositioner: function() {
        var tickPositions = this.tickPositions;

        for (var i = tickPositions.length; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (tickPositions[i] > this.dataMax) {
                tickPositions.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }

        return tickPositions
    }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/v6pc4r7n/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.tickPositioner